# Swift_RfcComplianceException Address in mailbox given [required|unique:users,email] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2

Tags: php, laravel, validation, sentinel

I am using cartalyst sentinel and i am validating user with validation but i am unable to find the problem where i am doing wrong:

My Controller:

```
public function postRegister(Request $request)
{
    $fieldsValidation = [

        'email'      => 'required|unique:users,email',
        'first_name' => 'required',
        'last_name'  => 'required',
        'password'   => 'required',

    ];
    $user = Sentinel::register($fieldsValidation);
    $activation = Activation::create($user);

    $this->sendEmail($user, $activation->code);
    return redirect()->back()->with([
        'success' => 'user registered successfully'
    ]);
}
```

when i hit action i got the error

> Swift_RfcComplianceException Address in mailbox given
>   [required|unique:users,email] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.

i want to validate user with unique email and other fields validation:
Your help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Check RFC 2822, it seems you don't have a `from` and/or `reply-to` address set up: http://www.rfc-base.org/txt/rfc-2822.txt

Comment: i dont understand from this link can u tell me the exact answer

Comment: I said that? If you send emails without a `sender`, `from` and `reply-to` address, you don't comply with RFC 2822 and SwiftMailer will refuse to send your email.

Comment: my email is sendig here the question is i want to validate email that same email should not be entered and there should be message this email is already exist this is what i want but when i enter same email it through me this error

Answer (score 0):

Though you might have solved this by now still i thought it may help someone later on so

```
$v = \Validator::make($request->all(), $fieldsValidation);
          if ($v->fails())
          {
              //Validation failed                      
          }else{    
              //Code to create user
          }
```

That's how you can manage that only unique users get register

And for your invalid mail exception error you have to give email specification in mail.php file under app/config file, laravel will fetch it from there. Or you can specify it in env in then use it there

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST= 
MAIL_PORT=
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=
MAIL_ADMIN=
MAIL_SIGNATURE =
MAIL_FROM_NAME=
```

So check whether your configuration is correct or not. And you're good to go

Hope this helps.